# How to find direct url of camera in a .h264 dvr

Tags: dvr

I have a dvr that I can access using web interface. (http://[dvr-ip]:[port])

I can access the camera OK on that address all 8 channels.

What I want to do is to be able to view the page without being asked for a username and password or at least automatically enter username and password on the input boxes.

Tried googling about my dvr model and not much significant result.

The index.html file where I login has this fields

```
<td>
<input type="password" id="dvr_pwd" value="" size="20" style="width:150px;" />
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" id="dvr_usr" value="admin" size="20" style="width:150px;" onfocus="show_suggest()" onDblClick="show_suggest()" />
</td>
```

I was hoping that if I tried using url

```
http://[mydvrip]:[port]/index.html?dvr_usr=viewonly&dvr_pwd=viewonlypassword
```

will automatically enter username and password but it didn't.

I want to embed it on a webpage where public can view it without being asked for password.

Any idea how can I do that?

EDIT: (additional info)
I have managed to port forward so that my dvr IP is visible from internet. Just need to be able to get around the username and password

Thanks

Comment: Please try the following URL:
http : / / viewonly:viewonlypassword@[mydvrip]:[port] (added spaces avoid URL sanitizer). Normally this does not work with forms authentication, but let's hope that DVR's manufacturer implemented it.
What DVR are you using? Maybe it is possible to find the URL in documentation.

Comment: the box said "golden Gate dvr. model number is GGV-8001 as displayed on web interface. I tried your suggestion and it goes back to index.html of the dvr where I have to enter username and password. not sure if this is relevant but my dvr is is working with this android app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ESeye&hl=en

Comment: I was able to find the user manual of my DVR http://www.yerphi.am/cc/CLIENT/DVR%20Manual.doc but it still does not mention how to connect to the camera directly. Anyone out there who manage to connect to camera using this DVR it will be highly appreciated if you can share how to access the camera directly. Thanks @Mbu